# Free struct stored in an array

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I am currently working on a **virtual Filesystem**. There are no actual physical folders or files, its just about practising data structures. To create a File or a Folder i have this struct:

```
struct FS_Object {
    int32_t id;
    struct FS_Object* parent;
    dataType dataType;
    FolderInfo  folderInfo;
    FileInfo    fileInfo;
};
```

FolderInfo and FileInfo are structs that contain an ID, a name and some other attributes.

Im **storing** every created struct **in a global array** to have access to the properties:

```
FS_Object* dataList;
```

**So if I want to free a previous created FS_Object (lets say stored in dataList[1]):**

FS_Objects are created like this:

```
FS_Object fsObject = malloc(sizeof(struct FS_Object));
```

1. Check if the element exists

```
if (dataList[1] != NULL) ...
```

2. Free FolderInfo struct from FS_Object struct like this:

```
FolderInfo *folderInfo = &dataList[1]->folderInfo;
free(folderInfo);
folderInfo = NULL;
```

3. Free FileInfo:

```
fileInfo *fileInfo = &dataList[1]->fileInfo;
free(fileInfo);
fileInfo = NULL;
```

4. Finally free the FS_Object struct itself:

```
free(dataList[1]);
dataList[1] = NULL;
```

Is this the right approach? I am currently getting the following exception when I'm trying to free the FolderInfo struct:

```
*** Error in `./filesystem': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001fa70e8 ***
```

Comment: There is a lot that seems wrong in your code, but I think this question should better be asked in codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You are malloc'ing memory for an FS_Object, then trying to free memory in the middle of it ("folderInfo"). You can't do this. It seems very likely that you INTENDED for "folderInfo" and "fileInfo" to be pointers.

Comment: No, your approach is not right. `folderInfo` and `fileInfo` are nested in `FS_Object` - they aren't pointers you obtained from `malloc` so you don't need to free them. You should only be `free`ing the `FS_Object` instances you `malloc`.

Comment: Good rule of thumb is, free everything in reverse order of the way you malloc memory

Comment: Your global array should be an array of pointers, e.g. `FS_Object *dataList[100]`. Or you can declare `dataList` as `FS_Object **dataList`, and then `malloc` space for it.

Comment: I am using malloc to create space for my dataList like this: 
dataList = calloc(MAX_OBJECTS,  sizeof(struct FS_Object));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If folderInfo is a bare struct (in opposition to a pointer to a struct), you shouldn't need to free it (it is allocated when you malloc FS_Object). Since you didn't malloc it, you don't need to free it.

So you can basically remove steps in number (2) and (3).

Check this question: [Malloc of arrays and structs within a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465759/malloc-of-arrays-and-structs-within-a-struct)